# Off-network code management on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a couple of Raspberry Pi's scatted around friend's houses, doing stuff like monitoring a temperature sensor, running a garage door opener, controlling blinds etc.

Each Pi has a different codebase - essentially, a few Python and bash files in the homedir. One of these files (hook.sh) is triggered on boot, so it kicks everything else off including an updater script that periodically checks what version I've flagged as appropriate for that Pi remotely. If the version doesn't match what's on there, it downloads a rar of new code, junks the existing files, moves the new code across and reboots.

This works well but it's not incredibly elegant and I'm sure I'm not the first person to encounter this problem. Is there some standardized way of doing this? If you had a fleet of remote pi's (without fixed IPs you could conveniently SSH into) how would you deploy different code to them or sync their filesystems with a remote repository?

Not looking for code - just ideas. I have a fantasy of maintaining several folders (one for each pi) on my development machine and they somehow magically sync to the remote pi's. Wishful thinking?

Comment: Use a Version Control System, and have your software pull from it. [Github](https://github.com) for example.